# Is there an Artifactory API call that creates a folder?

Tags: rest, artifactory

What am I missing here? I'm using the `Create Directory` API call because I want to create a directory. What ends up happening with this is that it creates a file with the name that I've specified.

`myrepostore.jfrog.io/artifactory/<parentDirectory>/<newDirectory>` is the syntax where `newDirectory` should be the directory that I'm attempting to create with this PUT method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a folder using the Artifactory REST API, you should indicate your intention by adding a forward slash at the end of the folder name in the API endpoint. This helps Artifactory understand that you want to create a folder rather than a file.

Example:

```
curl -u<username>:<password> -XPUT "http://my.jfrog.artifactory:8081/artifactory/generic-local/a/"
```

This will upload a directory called 'a' under an existing repository generic-local of type 'Generic'

Note: The generic-local should exist prior to adding the sub folder.